# Command not getting called when MenuItem is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a context menu that gets called when a listview is right-clicked. After doing some research I found out that this is how you bind a command to a menuitem.

```
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete">
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Any help on why the command isn't firing would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
```

will do it for you.

`ItemContainerStyle` is used when there is `ItemsSource` for `MenuItem`.

[CodeProject for Menu+Commands](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37848/WPF-Data-Bound-Menus)